# Can't run catch test: MACRO CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER is never used

Tags: cmake, try-catch, clion

I am trying to run run my first test in Clion using catch. Clion shows an error, squigly underlined, for the MACRO CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER which reads: Can't run catch test: MACRO CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER is never used. The program compiles and runs fine however I can't run the test. I added a configuration to run the test, but if I do Clion just spins while showing: instantiating tests. What am I missing? Please see below the code and makefile.

```cpp
//This program reads identifies the largest # of three integers
#include <iostream>
#define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER
#include "catch.hpp"

using namespace std;

int largestInt ( int x, int y, int z); //function declaration/prototype

TEST_CASE("Find the largest of three numbers", "[eight is the answer]") {
    REQUIRE(largestInt(8, 5, 4) == 8);
}

int main() {
    int num1, num2, num3, max;

    cout << "Please enter three integers: ";
    cin>> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

    max = largestInt(num1, num2, num3);

    cout << "The largest number is " << max;

    return 0;
}

//this function returns the largest of three ints
int largestInt ( int x, int y, int z) {  //function definition
    int max = x;

    if (y > max) {
        max = y;
    }

    if (z > max) {
        max = z;
    }
    return max;
}

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(6_3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include_directories(/home/mgalactico/Documents/Deitel_Exercises/catch)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp ../catch/catch.hpp)
add_executable(6_3 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written your own main() function. I assume you have a good reason for not generating one with the CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN macro. What is missing here is telling the program when to run the tests. This can be before, in between or after the code of your main function. Catch will not guess and decide that for you. You run the tests by calling:

```
Catch::Session().run(argc, argv);
```

This will create you an instance of Catch::Session which can also be done in a separate instruction followed by a call of applyCommandLine

```
Catch::Session session;
auto result = session.applyCommandLine( argc, argv );
// error handling ( result ) ...
...
```

Pass the command line arguments because the behavior of catch is configured this way. This is used by CLion where Catch is now (2017.1 or later) integrated. That means you get a green/red progress bar test runner as well as statistics and reporting if you have selected catch in your configuration.